# html video pixelated/lagging in Iball slide device

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, video, html5-video

When I am launching a video tag from Cordova and playing a *webm format video within a Video tag in Iball slide(A:4.4.2) device. I am seeing distortions of pixels and running lines on the screen.

Tried preloading the video and giving timeout delay to the play function 1000ms.

The video is playing fine on other devices.

snap:
[image snap for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHWA5.jpg)

[another snap for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKMEi.jpg)

Comment: might that be a media decoder issue? what other devices Did you try that on ?

Comment: @sud007,
I am facing this issue only in these particular devices. It renders fine in other lower end devices.